# Normals Disable Smooth Shading?

Tags: shaders

I'm having an issue that whenever I input a normal map into a shader normal node in blender 2.9 it disables smoothing for that object and the polygon face edges become visible in the render.

Any idea why?

Comment: please share 2.9!!!

Comment: If any of the objects were baked with shading set to flat then that will be on the normal map as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a packing issue, when I unpacked the normal map into an external folder it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a question: which is more high-res, your object, or the normal map? If the object is more high-res, than the normal map is going to hide that with it's low-res faces.